# Typescript error: Property is used before being assigned

Tags: typescript

Typescript shows **[ts] Property 'logger' is used before being assigned** in VSCode. The error occurs in code below at `this.logger.logInfo(Important, ...`. I'm very clearly setting this property on second line of the constructor so...?

If I used the `self` var shown in code (self.logger.logInfo...), the TS error goes away but this should not be necessary.

Thank you for sharing your expertise :-)

```
// app/data/mongo/_base.data.mongo.ts 

import { MongoClient, ObjectId } from 'mongodb';
import { IBaseModel } from '../../model/_base.model';
import { Logger, Important, NotImportant } from '../../util/logger';

export default class BaseData {

    constructor(params: any) {
        this.collectionName = params.collectionName;
        this.logger = new Logger(this.collectionName);
        if (this.db) {
            this.collection = this.db.getCollection(this.collectionName);
        } else {
            BaseData.userId = params.user.id;
            BaseData.userHandle = params.user.handle;
            this.dbServer = params.dbServer;
            this.dbPort = params.dbPort || '27017';
            this.dbName = params.dbName;
            const self = this; // This is a Typescript BUG!
            (async () => {
                const url = `mongodb://${this.dbServer}:${this.dbPort}`;
                this.db = await MongoClient.connect(url, { "useNewUrlParser": true });
                this.collection = this.db.collection(this.collectionName);
                this.logger.logInfo(Important, 'contructor', `MongoDb connection (${url}) success!`);
            })();
        }
    }

    static userId: string;
    static userHandle: string;

    protected logger: Logger;
    protected collectionName: string = '';
    protected client: any;
    protected collection: any;
    protected db: any;
    protected dbServer: string = '';
    protected dbPort: string = '';
    protected dbName: string = '';
```

Comment: This error doesn't occur in the TypeScript Playground with the provided code. Can you provide a **self-contained** example so people are able to help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is some self-contained code that reproduces the issue:

```
// Turn on --strictNullChecks and --strictPropertyInitialization
class Foo {
    prop: string;
    constructor() {
        this.prop = "assigned";
        (async () => {
            this.prop; // error, used before assigned
        })();
    }
}
```

[View on the Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%2F%2F%20Turn%20on%20--strictNullChecks%20and%20--strictPropertyInitialization%0D%0Aclass%20Foo%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20prop%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor%28%29%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.prop%20%3D%20%22assigned%22%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%28async%20%28%29%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.prop%3B%20%2F%2F%20error%2C%20used%20before%20assigned%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%29%28%29%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A) (remember to turn on `--strictNullChecks` and `--strictPropertyInitialization` compiler options).

---

This may well be a design limitation in TypeScript, if not a full-fledged bug.  The fact is that automated control flow analysis is [hard to do "right"](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998).  Since it's generally impossible for the compiler to figure out exactly which states are possible for each variable at each point in a program, it has to use heuristics, which tend to result both in false negatives (uncaught bugs) and false positives (caught non-bugs).  This seems like a false positive to me, since the asynchronous function is definitely invoked after `this.prop` has been set.  [A similar issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9757) has been raised and addressed before, with *synchronous* immediately-invoked function expressions.

I think someone more knowledgeable about the specifics of how TypeScript does control flow analysis would be needed to speak authoritatively here, but I'm guessing that this particular case just hasn't been anticipated or encountered enough to handle it.  If you think you have a compelling use case for this, you may want to [file an issue in GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues), assuming nobody provides a more satisfying answer to this question.

Meanwhile, if you have a workaround, such as assigning `const self = this` and then accessing `self.prop`, or the equivalent accessing of `(this as this).prop`, then I guess you should use it.  And there's always the sledgehammer of all workarounds, the [`//@ts-ignore` comment](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html#suppress-errors-in-ts-files-using--ts-ignore-comments):

```
class Foo {
  prop: string;
  constructor() {
    this.prop = "assigned";
    (async () => {
      // @ts-ignore: this.prop is really assigned before being used
      this.prop;
    })();
  }
}
```

---

Oh well, sorry I don't have better news.  Hope that helps in any case.  Good luck!